# Get the name of the Parent of a child Panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls, panel

I have a Panel object, which was dynamically created within another Panel object that was also dynamically created.
How can I get the name of the parent Panel from the child Panel?.

I only found information related to the Form object.

Comment: Why would you want the name? If they were created at run time, there may not even be a name, unless you set one explicitly. Surely what you actually want is the `Panel` itself, not its name. You'd have to actually get the `Panel` itself first anyway, and then you can get the `Name` property like you would any other property.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of methods that may help in finding the child's Parents.

The direct parent of a Control is returned by the `Control.Parent` property:

```
Dim parentName = [SomeControl].Parent.Name
```

The Form container is returned by the [FindForm()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.findform) method or the [`Control.TopLevelControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.toplevelcontrol) property:

```
Dim myForm1 = [SomeControl].FindForm()
Dim myForm2 = [SomeControl].TopLevelControl
Dim myFormName1 = myForm1.Name
Dim myFormName2 = myForm2.Name
```

You may also use [GetContainerControl()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.getcontainercontrol), this returns the outermost [IContainerControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.icontainercontrol).

A UserControl can use the [ParentForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform) property (but it's the same as `FindForm()`)

To find the outer container that is not a Form:

```
Private Function FindOuterContainer(ctrl As Control) As Control
    If ctrl Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    While Not (TypeOf ctrl.Parent Is Form)
        ctrl = FindOuterContainer(ctrl.Parent)
    End While
    Return ctrl
End Function

Dim outerContainer = FindOuterContainer([SomeControl])
Dim outerContainerName = outerContainer.Name
```

To find the outer ancestor of a specific type (e.g., you have a Panel inside a Panel inside a TabPage of a TabControl and you want to know what TabPage that is):

```
Private Function FindOuterContainerOfType(Of T)(ctrl As Control) As Control
    If ctrl Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    While Not ((TypeOf ctrl.Parent Is Form) OrElse (TypeOf ctrl Is T))
        ctrl = FindOuterContainerOfType(Of T)(ctrl.Parent)
    End While
    Return ctrl
End Function

Dim parentTabPage = FindOuterContainerOfType(Of TabPage)([SomeControl])
Console.WriteLine(parentTabPage.Name)
```

To find the outermost Parent of a specific type:
(e.g., you have a Panel inside a Panel inside a TabPage of a TabControl which is inside a Panel and you want to get this last Panel)

```
Private Function FindOuterMostContainerOfType(Of T)(ctrl As Control) As Control
    If ctrl Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    Dim outerParent As Control = Nothing
    While Not (TypeOf ctrl.Parent Is Form)
        If TypeOf ctrl.Parent Is T Then outerParent = ctrl.Parent
        ctrl = ctrl.Parent
    End While
    Return If(TypeOf outerParent Is T, outerParent, Nothing)
End Function


Dim outermostParentPanel = 
    TryCast(FindOuterMostContainerOfType(Of Panel)([SomeControl]), Panel)
Dim outermostParentPanelName = outermostParentPanel?.Name
```

**`[SomeControl]`** is of course the instance of the child Control that wants to find its Parents.